# Include custom javascript in the footer of wp-login.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some javascript code that I have managed to include in the footer of pages except wp-login.php page, using `wp_footer` action.

I have to do it using a plugin.

This action is not including javascript on `wp-login.php` page.
I have searched for hooks for this purpose with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this hook `login_footer`. It must include your custom javascript in `wp-login.php` page.